# Specify Key Path in a List Swift UI

Tags: xcode, list, swiftui, swift-keypath

I have below structure , where `GroceryData` has details about the section as `[GrocerySection]` , this in turn has items to be displayed in the section as `[Grocery]`.

```
struct GroceryData {
    var showFavorites:Bool = false
    var sections:[GrocerySection] = [GrocerySection(sectionName: "Common Items")]

}

struct GrocerySection {
    var sectionName:String
    var items:[Grocery] = [Grocery(id:1, name: "Milk", isFavorite: true, price: 1.99)]
}



struct Grocery: Identifiable,Hashable, Codable {
    var id:Int
    var name:String
    var isFavorite:Bool
    var price:Float
}
```

What should be the key path for the identifiable property.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var data:GroceryData
    var body: some View {
        List(data.sections, id: \GrocerySection.items.id) { (item) -> Text in
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

since you are dealing with sections, this may work:

```
    List(data.sections, id: \.self.sectionName) { section in
        Text("hello section \(section.sectionName)")
    }
```

as long as the sectionName is unique, otherwise you can always add and id field.

If you want to loop over items you can try this:

```
    List(data.sections, id: \.self.sectionName) { section in
        ForEach(section.items) { item in
            Text("\(item.name)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably not , as with further changes it will have Row items inside the content

Comment: don't fully understand your comment. Does the code work or not? Do you want to loop over some other things?

Comment: An identifiable KeyPath is required for items.id ,  where items is an array of type Grocery. Grocery object has id of type Int and grocery conforms to Identifiable protocol

Comment: your List is for an array of GrocerySection, it needs and id for GrocerySection, either sectionName or items. But items is just an array, it does not really identify the different sections. From you code it seems you are expecting a Grocery item from the list, but you only can get a GrocerySection. Once you have that you can get to the items.

Answer (score 0):

You iterate list of sections so `GrocerySection` must be identifiable, like

```
struct GrocerySection: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()        // << this
//     var id: String { sectionName }   // << or even this
    var sectionName:String
    var items:[Grocery] = [Grocery(id:1, name: "Milk", isFavorite: true, price: 1.99)]
}
```

then you can write

```
List(data.sections) { (section) -> Text in
    Text("Hello")
}
```

or using keypath if every section name is unique, as

```
List(data.sections, id: \.sectionName) { (section) -> Text in
    Text("Hello")
}
```